# Calculate 3D-coordinates of a cube's points from the points on the projections

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, triangulation

I have a following optical system: 3 cams (left and top, which is orthogonal to the left, and right, which is parallel to the left and orthogonal to the top) and the 2 cubes in the 3D-space with following coordinate system:
[image: optical system]
Each of the points $P_t$, $P_l$, $P_r$ lies in the middle point of the appropriated side on the cube. The length of the each cube's side (left and right) is $c$ (in mm). The cubes are parallel to each other. The distance between the points $P_lP_r = w$

From the optical recognition (matching) I know the 2D-coordinates of these points on the projections in px: $P'_l = (P'_lx, P'_ly)$, $P'_t = (P'_tx, P'_ty)$, $P'_r = (P'_rx, P'_ry)$. The distances from the origin to the projection are also defined: $OO_l = d_l$, $OO_l = d_l$, $OO_r = d_r$ in mm.

The focal lengths $f_l$, $f_t$ and $f_r$ can be also defined and used if needed.

In order to calculate the 3D-coordinates of the cube I need to calculate the scale factor that allows to covert the projections 2D-coordinate in px to the real coordinate in mm.

So how is can I calculate the $P_lx$, $P_lz$ in mm (from the left projection), $P_tx$, $P_ty$ in mm (from the top projection), $P_rx$, $P_rz$ in mm (from the left projection)?

Can someone please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Are we to assume the size of the cube is infinitesimally small? Otherwise the position of the cube's center is not uniquely defined. For example, suppose you knew the positions of $P_l$ and $P_t$ precisely, the cube can spin around the line connecting the two points and still satisfy your constraints.

Comment: Yes, you've right, I wanted first only to focus the main part of the system. Now I have edited the post and you'll see the whole system. It consists one object with 2 cubes and the 3 cameras. In this case you can obtain 2 of 3 rotation angles to specify the cubes position. Can you help me now to solve the problem?